# Enumerating all references in a perl interpreter

Tags: perl, memory-leaks, introspection

The problem at hand is finding a memory leak.  I have used Devel::Refcount to show which of the objects in my application is retained in memory when they should not be.

Three methods have been proposed to find the elusive links to these structures.

1 - perhaps a data structure exists that lets me get the list of symbols referring to my object, this would be ideal and direct.

2 - iterate the symbol tables in all defined namespaces looking for the references and use the iteration stack to determine where it is.

3 - insert a hook that lets me record the stack position when a particular reference's link count has been changed up or down and the address of the symbol that is holding the link.  I can use that to find which symbols are holding my reference directly.

So is this possible?  This kind of introspection is tricky stuff, and I may know perl really well, but I don't know how to do this.  My research into padwalker which seems like it might have the key has not born fruit.  Your thoughts?

Comment: Note that you can access the refcount using builtin `Internals::SvREFCNT(%$self)`

Comment: I have the refcount.  I want the namespace definitions of the structures whom are holding the refcount non-zero, and who is holding THAT structure's refcount nonzero, etc, until I find the variable with a defined value in scope that should not be.

Comment: I believe you have the final refcnt. Since you know which object is leaking, you can use this function and standard debugging to locate the leak.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Test::LeakTrace](https://metacpan.org/release/Test-LeakTrace)?

```
#!perl
use Test::LeakTrace;

no_leaks_ok {
    # Suspect code here
};
```

This runs the block several times, and then if all the Perl values in the interpreter increases, Test::LeakTrace thinks there are memory leaks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to tell me where the allocation occurred (something I already know by application context) I want to know who has a non-weak ref to that previously created reference.

Answer (score -2):

You could try iterating through the :: hash; that's that's main namespace, which maps symbol names to values.  Any keys in that namespace that end in :: are namespaces that can be iterated through either by iterating the value you got from the namespace, or just treating that namespace as a hash; i.e.

```
>perl -le 'print foreach keys %::'
version::
/
stderr
_<mro.c
Tie::
utf8::
"
re::
CORE::
DynaLoader::
mro::
stdout
attributes::

stdin
ARGV
INC
ENV
Regexp::
UNIVERSAL::
$
_<perlio.c
main::
_<perlmain.c
PerlIO::
0
_<universal.c

@
_<xsutils.c
STDOUT
IO::

_
STDERR
Internals::
STDIN
DB::





   >perl -le 'print foreach keys %mro::'
    get_mro
    get_linear_isa
    get_pkg_gen
    set_mro
    invalidate_all_method_caches
    is_universal
    method_changed_in
    get_isarev
```

Comment: That will only lists package variables. Most variables aren't package variables.

Comment: This will find any variable in any namespace; whether it's a global or a package variable.  Lexical variables aren't in a namespace, so the part of the question I was answering doesn't apply there.

Comment: ("Whether it's a global or package variable" makes no sense. Every package variable is a global, and every global is a package variable.) Exactly, lexical and anonymous variables won't be found, and they could very well hold references to the object. In fact, it's almost certain to be one of those. Your answer isn't helpful, and it might cause the question to not get the attn it deserves.